# Is it possible to create Sandbox like Azure in Local Environment ?

Tags: azure, sandbox

When you create App in Azure it is isolated like D:\home . It is called Sandbox environment.

- Is it Docker Container ?
- Is it VM it self ?

As I have read some document it suggest that it is not docker container and VM. Is it possible to create such isolation manually in windows ?

Comment: Azure App Service is a container like services based on Service Fabric.You could use either Docker for Windows or Service Fabric to create similar isolation.    Azure App Service is not replicable in a VM.  If you would like to have similar instance in your On-Premise (within your enterprise infrastructure), you could try Azure Stack which can be installed on your data center and you will have your own private azure within your enterprise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe there is an application to replicate the app service on your machine. However, if you were to publish your application in an container (ex Docker) you can replicate some of the functionality of the wep app on your machine. For this you should use a containerized web app.

You can replicate 
 - Machine overall behavior
 - Network firewall settings

You cannot replicate
 - Azure Sandbox machine limits (ex max threads, max connections ect)
 - Performance level (as this is app service plan specific)

Comment: I don't want some application but I feel that if we run app service it run on some machine at azure cloud and so there are some software or windows in built functionality that support this.

Comment: You are right, web apps (for windows apps) do run on Windows Server machines. The software they use to manage the machines however are inside the "magic black box of Azure" and not open for the public (it's their core software to run Azure). There is no way to get the software (legally) that runs to provision and manage the Web Apps & App Service Plans.